# chrome.tabs.executeScript não funciona no background

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensão

Gostaria de que, quando eu clicasse no botão da extensão, escrevesse no console o `title` da pagina.

Meu código atual é esse:

> background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
        code: 'console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText);'
    });
});
```

> manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "log print",
    "description": "usar console.log()",
    "version": "1",
    "permissions":[
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
        ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",
    "background": {
        "persistent": true,
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
        },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Teste",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
        },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

> popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>
      <button id="Mr_Button">hello this is a test</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que, se você tem um `default_popup` definido no seu arquivo de manifest, o evento `browserAction.onClicked` nunca é chamado.

A solução mais simples seria tirar o `default_popup`.

Outra solução seria chamar o `executeScript` pelo popup, veja como ficaria:

> popup.html

```
<script src="popup.js"></script>
```

> popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: 'console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerText);'
});
```